# ratio test is inconclusive

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

I have a series

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{cos(k)}{2*(k^3)-k}$

Using ratio test, I got

$={\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{cos(k+1)}{k*(2*(k+1)^2-1)}}/{\frac{cos(k)}{k*(2*(k^2)-1)}} = \frac{cos(\infty+1)}{cos(\infty)}*\frac{2-(1/(\infty)^2)}{2+4/(\infty)^2)+1/(\infty)^2}=1$ ([inconclusive](http://www.mathscoop.com/calculus/infinite-sequences-and-series/the-ratio-test.php))

But testing it in [online](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/limit-calculator/%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cfrac%7Bcos%5Cleft(k%5Cright)%7D%7B%5Cleft(2k%5E%7B3%7D-k%5Cright)%7D/?origin=button) calculators yields convergence results. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean with $\;\frac{\cos(\infty+1)}{\cos\infty}\;$ , and why you think, apparently, that this equals $\;1\;$ . Anyway, many times these or those tests can fail, and we must try other ones.

Comment: Ration test is frequently inconclusive, at which point you must look at the comparison test or the limit comparison test.  If your series is $\sum P(k)/Q(k)$ where P(k) and Q(k) are polynomials, then the ratio test will always be inconclusive.  But, you can do a limit comparison test to $1/k^a$, where a is the difference in degree between P(k) and Q(k).

Answer (score 1):

Directly with comparison:

$$\left|\frac{\cos k}{2k^3-k}\right|\le\frac1{k^3}\implies\;\text{since}\;\;\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^3}$$

converges then so our series converges *absolutely*, and thus it converges.

Comment: Thanks for the comparison test. I have to solve it using ratio test, that's why I asked.

Comment: @Mitty  You "have to" ? I don't think it is easily possible. Perhaps using some trick to find out the limit supremum...

Comment: You can't use the ratio test because the terms are not decreasing (due to the cos part).

Comment: @martycohen I don't think that being decreasing is a *condition* to use the ratio test. To be eventually non-negative is, though.